# .Net Core 3.1 - Method not found: Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Environ(System.String)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to port a .Net Framework 4.6 app to .Net Core 3.1. The app references a DLL from a Nuget package that was compiled using .Net Framework 4.6.

At runtime, the app fails with:

```
Method not found: Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Environ(System.String)
```

Obviously this method isn't included in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll that is part of .Net Core. Is there anyway to deal with this situation with a shim/polyfill or some other way? The app will still run on Windows Server.

Comment: If you can get at the source, you can replace the method call with [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @stuartd I tried to define a method with the same namespace/class name both in my project and in a separate project and neither worked. It seems the third-party library looks in Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core library and doesn’t see the method and throws an exception. Is there a way to force the code to look for the custom method in my project?

Comment: My mistake. The package code can’t see the method because it doesn’t have a reference to your project.

Comment: If your objective is to get the environment variable only, you might want to use the .NET Core equivalent Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable().

Comment: @victor6510 The problem is it’s a third-party library that I can’t change. Need some way to “mock” the VisualBasic method that doesn’t exist in .Net Core.

Comment: @user2966445 Sorry to overlook your question. Could you share about which nuget package you use? Let me try if I can create a mock or shim or something likes that.

Comment: @victor6510 It's a private Nuget package that's not available on Nuget.org. All you would need to do is spin up a .Net Framework 4.6 project with one method that calls `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Environ(System.String)`. Then reference the DLL/method in another .Net Core 3.1 project.